# Detecting which link opened in chrome custom tab

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

In webView we can detect user opend which link like following code:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onLoadResource(view, url);

        }
    }
    );
```

but in custom chrome tab i can't find a way to detect which link opend?

is it possible have control on internal link like webView in CustomTab?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to track the user navigation that's happening inside a Custom Tab from the host application.